# Python wordlist permutation

Tags: python, permutation, permute

How can i make this script to permute maximum of 3 combination of words from a list?

List.txt consists of 4 strings:

```
pass
10
test
word
```

Instead of combining all from one to four words i.e

```
output > pass10wordtest, 10testpassword,....etc
```

I want the final combination to be:

```
output > testpassword, passtestword, 10wordtest,....etc
```

My code:

```
from itertools import permutations
import os

# GET FILE
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
wordlist_rel_path = "List.txt"
wordlist_abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, wordlist_rel_path)

# READ WORD LIST FROM FILE
word_list = []
print ("\ninput file is:", wordlist_abs_file_path,"\n")
with open(wordlist_abs_file_path) as wordlist:
     for line in wordlist:
         word_list.append(line.rstrip())

# PRINT INPUT LIST
print ("input list contains:")
print(word_list,"\n")

# GENERATE POWERSET
powerset_list = []
print ("output list is:")
for n in range(1, len(word_list)+1):
     for perm in permutations(word_list, n):
         powerset_list.append( "".join(perm) )
print(powerset_list)

# WRITE LIST TO FILE
powerset_rel_path = "powerset.txt"
powerset_abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, powerset_rel_path)
powerset_abs_file = open(powerset_abs_file_path, 'w')
for item in powerset_list:
     powerset_abs_file.write("%s\n" % item)
powerset_abs_file.close()
```

Answer (score 7):

> How can I permute maximum of 3 combination of words from a list?

The [*permutations*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) function supports a second argument to select only three inputs at a time:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> for group in permutations(['pass', '10', 'test', 'word'], 3):
        print(''.join(group))  

pass10test
pass10word
passtest10
passtestword
password10
passwordtest
10passtest
10password
10testpass
10testword
10wordpass
10wordtest
testpass10
testpassword
test10pass
test10word
testwordpass
testword10
wordpass10
wordpasstest
word10pass
word10test
wordtestpass
wordtest10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import permutations
import os

# GET FILE 
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
wordlist_rel_path = "List.txt"
wordlist_abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, wordlist_rel_path)

# READ WORD LIST FROM FILE
word_list = [] print ("\ninput file is:", wordlist_abs_file_path,"\n")
with open(wordlist_abs_file_path) as wordlist:
     for line in wordlist:
         word_list.append(line.rstrip())

# PRINT INPUT LIST 
print ("input list contains:")
print(word_list,"\n")

# GENERATE POWERSET 
powerset_list = []
print ("output list is:") 
for n in range(1, len(word_list)+1):
     for perm in permutations(word_list,3):
         powerset_list.append( "".join(perm) ) print(powerset_list)

# WRITE LIST TO FILE 
powerset_rel_path = "powerset.txt" 
powerset_abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, powerset_rel_path) 
powerset_abs_file = open(powerset_abs_file_path, 'w') for item in powerset_list:
powerset_abs_file.write("%s\n" % item) powerset_abs_file.close()
```